# DIV appear on click (multiple areas)

Tags: jquery, html, click, toggle

Currently, I have a DIV that, when you click on it, another DIV appears.  Works fine.  However, if I try to add the same id's down the page a bit to do the effect again, I get nothing.  Here is my script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#click").click(function(){
    $("#fade").fadeToggle();
  });
});
  </script>
```

and then in the HTML I have:

```
<div id="click">Click Here!
<div id="fade">CONTENT HERE
</div>
</div>
```

which I said, work fine, until I try to do it again.  Is there a way to make it so I can do this as many times as I want without rewriting the script with different id's (there has to be a more efficient way than that)

Comment: Use `classes` instead of `ids`

Answer (score 1):

Use class instead of repeating ids and use class selector to bind the event and finding the element with class `fade` withing the clicked element using context in selector.

```
<div class="click">Click Here!
<div class="fade">CONTENT HERE
</div>
</div>


</<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".click").click(function(){
    $(".fade", this).fadeToggle();
  });
});
</script>div>
```

Comment: [You have to replace `id` attribute with `class`.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18314414/1420197)

Comment: Actually, theres a problem.  That works, but when you click anywhere within what is shown it minimizes again which won't work because I have text fields in the div that is shown.  Is there a way I can make it so only if I click the top it will disappear?

Answer (score 1):

The id has to be unique in a document. From [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html):

> `id = name [CS]`
>   This attribute assigns a name to an element. **This name must be unique in a document.**
>
> `class = cdata-list [CS]`
>   This attribute assigns a class name or set of class names to an element. Any number of elements may be assigned the same class name or names. Multiple class names must be separated by white space characters.

Solution is to replace the `#click` id with the `.click` class:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="click">Click Here!
    <div class="fade">CONTENT HERE</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".click").click(function(){
    $(".fade", this).fadeToggle();
  });
});
```

Also `#fade` id has to be replaced with `.fade` class because you are selecting `.fade` inside of clicked element (`this`).

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/AV2Xz/)

Answer (score 0):

**id="YOUR_ID_NAME"** is a uniq id in your document.

if you want to reuse your jquery then you can use class

otherwise you can take multiple id in your jquery

Here is code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#click,#click1,#click2").click(function(){
    $(".fade", this).fadeToggle();
  });
});




<div class="click">Click Here!
    <div id="fade">CONTENT HERE</div>
</div>

<div id="click1">Click Here!
    <div class="fade">CONTENT HERE</div>
</div>

<div id="click2">Click Here!
    <div class="fade">CONTENT HERE</div>
</div>
```

For better to use class for your document. If you want to reuse in your jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".click").click(function(){
    $(".fade", this).fadeToggle();
  });
});


<div class="click">Click Here!
<div id="fade">CONTENT HERE
</div>
</div>
```